# Updating table with a stored procedure using WHERE?

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-update, where-clause

I need to modify a stored procedure that will update a price table on a live database.
I am using MS SQL Server 2005, and the stored procedure is used as a query in SAP BI.

I have this part:

```
SET @cmd ='Update PriceList 5'
SET @sql ='UPDATE a SET a.price= round( (b.price*0.9),0), a.currency=b.currency  FROM      ['+@trgDB+'].[dbo].[ITM1] a '
SET @sql =@sql+' INNER JOIN ['+@trgDB+'].[dbo].[ITM1] b ON ( a.ItemCode=b.itemcode AND   b.PriceList=1) '
SET @sql =@sql+' WHERE a.PriceList=5 '
IF @filter IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    SET @sql =@sql+' AND a.[ItemCode] LIKE '+char(39)+@filter+'%'+char(39)+' '
    SET @cmd = @cmd+' ('+@filter+'%'+') '
END
```

This will update the price on every item acording to filter. 
I need to leave some items unchanged, so how can I add  NOT LIKE 'VSK%' AND NOT LIKE 'VFH%' to the code above? It doesn't matter if the flter is left out, but then I need every price to be updated except NOT LIKE 'VSK%' AND NOT LIKE 'VFH%' .

[table http://qupload.com/images/clipbosjs.jpg](http://qupload.com/images/clipbosjs.jpg)

Comment: Please give us the basic structure of the table that you wish to update (name the most important columns) and give us a hint what VSK and VFH are. Have you any way to identify by id or category the items that shall not be updated?

Comment: I have uploaded the structure of the table above, and those are the items that I don't want to be updated by the stored procedure, everything else can be updated (or acording to the exiting filter)

Comment: I forgot to mention, this is a part from a stored procedure runing under MS SQL server 2005, and it is used for updating price lists in SAP BI.

Comment: To make it easier for others to help you could add more information by  editing your question and put the information from the comments into it. Give details about itemcode, `@filter` and so on. Add the SQL with little parameters as possible: `UPDATE a 
  SET a.price= round( (b.price*0.9),0),
      a.currency=b.currency  
  FROM ['+@trgDB+'].[dbo].[ITM1] a 
  INNER JOIN ['+@trgDB+'].[dbo].[ITM1] b 
  ON ( a.ItemCode=b.itemcode AND   b.PriceList=1) 
  WHERE a.PriceList=5 
  AND a.[ItemCode] LIKE '''+@filter+'%'+'';'
-- and Update the other table
Update PriceList 5 ' ('+@filter+'%'+') '`